# How to check if String contains only operators?

Tags: java, string

How to check if String contains only operators?

code:

```
 public void convertString(String s){
    String[] arr = s.split("");


    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length ; i++) {
        stringStack.push(arr[i]);
    }
    
     if (stringStack.peek().matches("[0-9]+")){
         digitStack.push(Double.valueOf(stringStack.pop()));
     }else if (stringStack.peek().matches("[(+=-*/^)]+")){

     }

     System.out.println(digitStack);

}
```

in this line `"[(+=-*/^)]+"` a receive error:

`Illegal character range (to < from)`

How to check if `String` contains only operators?

Comment: Not related to the question, but you might want to add `%` as the mod operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-` in `[  ]` has a special meaning, e.g. `[0-9]`.

Add an escape character, and it should work. `[(+=\-*/^)]+`

Comment: An alternative may be to put the dash to the end of the character class. In my opinion, it'll make it a little bit more readable.

Comment: The OP use `( )` to capture groups, in this case add dash to start or end may not works.

Comment: I'm not use  ( ) to capture groups, it's put in matches() method

Comment: You can put `-` at the beginning to make it lose special meaning, so you don't need to escape it -- `[-(+=*/^)]+`

Answer (score 0):

You have actually two options:

1. Escape the dash with a backslash (`\-` instead of `-`). That'll instruct the regex engine to parse the dash as a literal dash, instead of a range divider. This is what Zen already mentioned.
2. The second option is to put the dash at the beginning or at the end of the character class. If the dash is place in either, then the regex engine knows that the dash is not part of a *character range*.

   ```
   [(+=*/^)-]
   ```